# Recover Metamask Seed Phrase on android phone

Tags: metamask, recovery, password, passphrase, recover

I updated my Meta application on my android phone and they asked again for my seed phrase. I only remember my password. Is there a way to log in again?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the official app? One of the first task when creating the account they suggest to make a backup copy. If you continue having issues I suggest to contact their customer support.

Comment: Yes. I am using the official app on my android device. I've updated before and it only asked for my password but recently it asked for my phrase.